# How to get a whole background image on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have created a website that is both for desktop and mobile. But on mobile, you can not see the whole background picture (missing some of the cup) because of the nav. How do I get the whole picture. When you have slide down, you can se the whole background picture and the cup. Can some one help me with that, please? :)

My website: http://odsgaardklausen.dk/DBS/DBS.php

Comment: Please post code in your question, not just a link to an outside site. This is unhelpful to future readers if the linked site changes or is removed. Furthermore, what specifically have you tried, and what's wrong?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry about that. I was unsure if you wanted all the code, so I thought it was better to add the website, but I see now.

I tried myself to add a padding-top to the body, but this didn't seem to work. I was not aware about the "-position" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a media query for the body to specify changing the `background-position` when in mobile view.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        (...)
        background-position: center 50px;
    }
}
```

The second value sets the vertical alignment of the targeted background, so in this case, you're pushing the image down 50px from the top of the body.

I should also note the media query is set to `767px` to match Bootstrap's media query for the navbar.

Answer (score 1):

As @Drew Kennedy says in the comment, but just wrap it in media query, otherwise you will have a white space on desktop.

```
@media only screen (max-width: 480px){
    body{
      background-position: center 50px;
    }
}
```